# PJSIP stop other tasks when callback

Tags: pjsip

I'm using PJSIP in order to make calls. I can make two or three calls at the same time, using a player to play a wave file.

```
void make_call(char *msgFile, char *num)
{
    //Some code to setup de code

    play_file(call_id, msgFile);
}

static int play_file(pjsua_call_id call_id,  char *msgFile)
{
    //Setup the file player

    //on_pjsua_wav_file_end_callback is the callba
    pjmedia_wav_player_set_eof_cb(player_media_port, eof_data, &on_pjsua_wav_file_end_callback);

}
```

Mx problem is when the on_pjsua_wav_file_end_callback by one call who is ended, the other calls stops playing untill the callback is ended. And they unpaused when the callback is ended.

What can I do in order to continue playing my other calls when one is running the callback?

Regards

Comment: I have written a C++ wrapper to PjSIP and in my application I never came across this behavior. Could you share your code. The way you are using the APIs.

Comment: You can have my code at this repo:
[link](https://github.com/Dazul/Synsip/blob/master/src/Call_Manager.c)

The interesting part is on CallManager.c. My code is messy, it needs a refactoring, but it works on my last test. Hope this can help you.